# How upload node_modules with serverless to aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, serverless-framework, serverless, serverless-webpack-plugin

I have project on serverless framework. I need to resize image. I wrote lambda function and install module `sharp`. Also I use `serverless-webpack`. In webpack I add `externals: ['sharp']` and add in serverless.yml next:

```
custom:
  webpack:
    includeModules:
      packagePath: './src/package.json'
```

I deployed it successfully but when I run lambda I get

> error: Cannot find module 'sharp'
>   maybe I doing something wrong. If need more information I can write it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `forceInclude`

```
# serverless.yml
custom:
  webpack:
    includeModules:
      forceInclude:
        - sharp
```

[Reference document](https://github.com/serverless-heaven/serverless-webpack#forced-inclusion)